# Date algorithm with leap days in c++

Tags: c++, date, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to make the user choose a certain date to be added to 1/1/2014 for example.
I did that successfully and I did all the calculations. However, when I add 60 days to 1/1/2014. I get 3/0/2014. I tried to avoid this by changing the days but that didn't work as well. In addition, if I added 800000 days, I get more than 12 months which also can't be true.
I tried to avoid this by having an if statement at the beginning by doing something like month>=12. However, it shouldn't be this case otherwise it will always be December if I choose to add 80000000 days for example. In addition, I am not sure how should I deal with the leap years in this situation because whenever I add an if statements before the year incrementation it gets back to 2014. This thing also happens when I try to use an if statement before the months incrementation.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Date
{
public:
    int day, year, monthnum;
    Date operator+(const Date&);
};

Date Date:: operator+(const Date& date)
{
    cout << "Enter a day" << endl;
    cin >> day;
    if(day>=1)
    {
    while(day<=30 && monthnum ==1 || day<=30 && monthnum ==3 || day<=30 && monthnum ==7 || day<= 30 && monthnum ==8 || day<=30 && monthnum == 10 || day<=30 && monthnum == 12)
    {
        return Date(date.day+day,date.monthnum ,date.year); 
    }

    while(day<=29 && monthnum ==9 || day<=29 && monthnum == 4 || day<=29 && monthnum == 6 || day<= 29 && monthnum == 11)
    {
        return Date(date.day+day,date.monthnum ,date.year);
    }
    while(day>=364)
    {
        day =day - 364;
        year++;
    }
    while(day>29 && monthnum ==9 || day>29 && monthnum == 4 || day>29 && monthnum == 6 || day>29 && monthnum == 11)
    {
        while(day>=29)
        {
        day = day -29;
        monthnum ++;
        }
    }
    while(day>30 && monthnum ==1 || day>30 && monthnum ==3 || day>30 && monthnum ==7 || day>30 && monthnum ==8 || day>0 && monthnum == 10 || day>30 && monthnum == 12)
    {
        while(day>=30)
        {
        day = day -30;
        monthnum ++;    
        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Day should be greater than 0 !";
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem ? or at least provide me with the logic for it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I will really appreciate a reason for the down vote.

Comment: You want your tests to run from large to small (ie. year -> month -> day)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but: ode formatting could be better (too much whitespace, indentation is all over the place, ...). I'm also not sure what the question is. So far I see a description of what you did but I have a hard time grasping what the problem is.

Comment: @chrisb2244 But I want to user to enter a day, not a year

Comment: @borgleader I am trying to avoid having 0 as a day because days can't be 0. I am also trying to avoid having a number greater than 12 as a month.

Comment: I mean, you have for example a test for `while(day>=364){day=day-364; year++}`. This needs to be your first check, since otherwise your days seem to be being counted many times.

Comment: Incidentally, why are you asking for your `cin >> day` within your overloaded `+` `operator`? You're going to need to pass the amount you want to add within your main function, and so it needs to be known separately from within the `+` operator.

Comment: @chrisb2244 I changed it to what you said but that made it worse for some reason. I am unable to change the date with this change. About your second question, yes I'm passing the amount withing my main function.

Comment: @rullzrullz Which bit? The year > month > day, or the `cin` within `main()` rather than `+`?

Comment: @chrisb2244 the year > month > day.

Comment: Your use of Date::operator+ here makes no sense. Anyway, just use proven algorithms: http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date_algorithms.html

Answer (score 2):

I've edited my answer to provide the code I used, along with a commentary of changes relative to your initially supplied code.

Full (working) code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Date
{
public:
    int day, year, monthnum;
    void operator+(int day);
    bool leapYear;
    void print_date()
    {
        std::cout << "The date after addition is: ";
        std::cout << (this->day +1) << "/" << (this->monthnum +1) << "/" << (this->year) << std::endl;
        // Year probably doesn't require a +1, but you can check.
    }
    int daysInMonth[12];
    void set_daysInMonth()
    {
        // This is a mess, and most of these are constant, and so don't need to be a part of this function.
        // Really, you need a set_daysInFeb() function, but you also need to set the values for the other
        // months at least once, so I just put them here.
        daysInMonth[0]=31;
        daysInMonth[2]=31;
        daysInMonth[4]=31;
        daysInMonth[6]=31;
        daysInMonth[7]=31;
        daysInMonth[9]=31;
        daysInMonth[11]=31;
        daysInMonth[3]=30;
        daysInMonth[5]=30;
        daysInMonth[8]=30;
        daysInMonth[10]=30;
        if (leapYear) { daysInMonth[1]=29;}
        else {daysInMonth[1]=28;}
    }
};

void Date:: operator+(int day_var)
{
    if(day_var>=1)
    {
            day_var += day;
        while(day_var>365)
        {
            if (year%4==0 && year%1000 !=0)
            {
                leapYear = true;
                if (day_var > 366)
                {
                    day_var = day_var-366;
                    year++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                leapYear = false;
                day_var = day_var-365;
                year++;
            }
        }

        set_daysInMonth();
        while (1)
        {
            if (day_var < daysInMonth[monthnum])
            {break;}
            day_var = day_var - daysInMonth[monthnum];
            monthnum ++;
            if (monthnum == 12)
            {
                year++;
                monthnum = 0;
                set_daysInMonth(); // This requires you to move some code around,
                // since it doesn't update the values in the right places.
            }
        }

        day = day_var;  // note that this is assigning remaining days (day_var)
                            // to the Date date_var.day variable    
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Day should be greater than 0 !";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int day=0;
    cout << "Enter a day" << endl;
    cin >> day;
    Date date_var;
    date_var.year = 2014;
    date_var.monthnum = 1;
    date_var.day = 3;
    date_var + day;
    date_var.print_date();
    return 0;
}
```

Initially you needed to remove the `cin >> day;` from your `+` operator, and place it instead within your `main()` function.

I implemented a `print_date()` function belonging to your `class Date` so that you can easily display the date held in the class.

I made the `+` operator a void operator. This is probably not a great plan, and might be worth changing, but working out how to return an appropriate class object seemed more effort. You could try `return this;` or something similar.

I added a `void set_daysInMonth()` function to allow you to instantiate an array holding the number of days in a month, with changing days in February for leap years. If the number of days entered cause the year to move into a leap year, it's likely that this won't work quite properly - you should check this and move some function calls around so that it properly checks the year, sets the days in February (`daysInMonth[1]`) and then after that checks through the loop.

A `while(1)` loop was used to reduce the number of days held in `day_var` until it fell below the number of days in the expected month, at which point a `break` would be triggered.

The Date class has no constructor, so it is created and assigned values in the `main()` function. You could consider writing two constructors, one with three int arguments, and the other blank, allowing you to write `Date new_date(day, month, year);` or `Date new_date; new_date.day = day;` etc.

Good luck with any changes you wish to make :)

Comment: What is the test `if (year%4==0 && year%1000 !=0)` supposed to do?  It isn't a leap year test (I think `if (year%4 == 0 && (year%100 != 0 || year %400 == 0))` is a leap year test).  Were you programming during the runup to the Y2K problem?

Comment: My code is doing the same thing despite the leap days. However, I still get 0 as a day with this implementation, which is the thing that I want to avoid having.

Comment: adding 724 with this implementation will cause a compiling error for some reason

Comment: To avoid the zeros, give your struct a print_date() function of some kind, and add one to the day, month, year as appropriate (so that they lie between 1 and 12, instead of 0 and 11 for months, etc)

Comment: I suppose also if you prefer month/day/year, you should list them in a different order to my edit just now :)

Comment: I did an if statement in my output function that checks if the result of day =0 and set it to 1, however, this will make a duplicate of day=0 and day=1. I mean there will be two 1/1/2014 and two 2/1/2014 and so on.

Comment: You need to add 1 to every value, like in the function I posted, not just values equal to zero. I've looked at coding a bit more of this and found another potential problem though - if you add years, months, days, but your starting date is not Jan 1st, then there exists the possibility you'll run over into the next year by adding less than a full year (eg, if you start on Dec 31st, and add 1 day, then `days` is not larger than 31 or 365, but both the month and the year should be incremented :/)

Comment: I have pretty much working code now. There are a few oddities in the actual return (off by a day or two) but I imagine that you could fix those pretty quickly by looking through where I've subtracted days. Let me know if you want me to edit it into my answer, or if you'd prefer to try find the solution yourself by working through what you already have (or some middle ground, with additional help but not a full solution)

Comment: It actually worked but in this case I'll need to start from 2/2/2015 instead of 1/1/2014. I was able to change the year to 2013 and thus it will be changed to 2014 because of the addition. However, I was unable to change the day and month to 0 in the constructor for some reason

Comment: Actually it worked for most numbers but when I tried to add 300 I get 0 as a day again. Can you please edit it to your answer so I can check what I did wrong.

Comment: Changed the previous implementation to add on the date_var.day to day_var at the start, before running checks, otherwise there's overlap at the end of months.

Answer (score 1):

There's a much easier way to do this. Look up the [Julian Date calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day). The idea is that Julian date values are sequential and dense on the integer space. So you can convert a date to Julian format, add an offset as a number of days, and convert it back to get the date that's that far away from the original date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the implementation is correct, but it seems like to me you're mixing days and months. Since it looks like you're only entering days as input, I would only use days, as a month is not a set number. I can't really tell what you're trying to do with months and days and subtracting.

First, if there are more than 365 days you count a year and subtract 365 days.
I think the most unambiguous way is to give every day of the year a month. That is, day 1 to 31 is January, day 32 to 59 is February, etc. Then once you have the month subtract off the number of days in the year before the month, so the 33rd day would be in February and the 33-31 = 2nd day.

Also I'm sure C++ has some kind of library for dates and counting.

Comment: what about day number 60000 ? how are you going to calculate it this way?

Comment: @rullzrullz In addition to it being pretty likely that a library could handle this for you, you can subtract off days per year pretty easily. If you're concerned about handling of leap years, you could consider subtracting the number of days in a 4 year cycle, and then moving to individual years.

Comment: Unfortunately, the C++ standard library doesn't have a library for dates, though boost, the unofficial C++ standard library, does.

Comment: @chrisb2244 That's true, however, the only library as Mooing Duck said, is boost which is not in C++ standard libraries.